# C preprocessor macros: compacting code based on a single variance

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

My issue is this: I have some macros that look like this:

```
#define _EI_PORTLETTER 'D'
...code...
#if _EI_PORTLETTER == 'C'
#define _EI_VECTOR PORTC_VECT
if _EI_PORTLETTER == 'D'
#define _EI_VECTOR PORTD_VECT
#endif
```

Then later in my code I have:

```
ISR(_EI_VECTOR, ISR_NAKED) {
...code...
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is define `_EI_PORTLETTER` and not have to rewrite my macros just because of the single letter changing (because there are a body of 6 of them, and I have more `_EI_PORTLETTERS` than just 'C' and 'D'). Is it possible?  That is, something like this:

```
#define _EI_PORTLETTER 'D'
...code...

#define _EI_VECTOR PORT _EI_PORTLETTER _VECT
```

or

```
#define _EI_VECTOR(x) PORT x _VECT
```

Such that the _EI_VECTOR, or _EI_VECTOR_(x), resolves to:

```
PORTD_VECT
```

(without any spacing around the D).

Is this possible using C macros?

It seems simple in my mind but I'm unable to do it. Yes, I have scoured Google and Stack Overflow, read the GCC docs. I have been  unable to figure out how to do what I want, or even know if it's possible.

Comment: You are not allowed to define macros starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter, those are reserved. For the rest, check out the token-pasting operator `#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
#define EI_PORTLETTER D
#define EI_VECTOR_(x) PORT ##x ##_VECT
#define EI_VECTOR2_(x) EI_VECTOR_(x)
#define EI_VECTOR EI_VECTOR2_(EI_PORTLETTER)
```

The `EI_VECTOR_` macro uses the token-pasting operator `##` to build the desired identifier.

The `EI_VECTOR2_` macro serves to indirect `EI_PORTLETTER` so that it is expanded as `D` instead of just being pasted as `EI_PORTLETTER`.